# Area under the curve without substitutions

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

Now in general when we try to find area under the curve using integrals, we substitute the value of y in terms of x (as derived from the equation of the curve) in the function given and find the area according to given limits.

But suppose I wished to find the area under the curve without substituting any variable in terms of the other, How would I do it?

**ASSUME there is a function , f(x,y)**

Now I tried three ways of solving

1. **The regular method of substituting y= some A(x)**
2. **By Partial Integration(*not integration by parts*)** 
   [Partial Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjhqh.png)
3. **By Double Integration** 
   [Double Integration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSpgK.png)

The answers are different in each case.
Can someone please explain?

For example lets assume **(y-2x-6)(y-3x+18)=f(x,y)** and the area of curve between the points: **(-4.8,-3.6) , (0,6) , (6,0) , (4.8,-3.6)** is to be found

I used the following integrals:

1)[Method 1 for solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCLYE.png)
2)[Method 2 for solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tapxe.png)
3)The usual method which gives the right answer

**Please Explain and provide the right method**

**Sorry my reputation does not allow image embedding so if someone might be kind enough to embedd them**

Comment: It sounds like you want the area under a *surface*, not a curve, in which case you would compute a double integral of $f(x,y)$. The limits you use are not correct, though.

Comment: But do i have to express everything in terms of either x or y for area under the curve.    Is there no way to find area under curve using multivariable calculus like an integral analogue of partial differentiation or something

Comment: In theory, you could use Green's theorem to relate your double integral to a line integral of a vector field, but that requires finding the right field $\vec F:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, $\vec F(x,y)=(f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$ such that $f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}$, which is generally difficult to do.